# ASP.NET MVC - RequireHttps - Specify a redirect URL

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, ssl, https

I'm using `[RequireHttps]` in my MVC2 application, but in my testing machine the SSL url is different from the actual site url (it's a shared SSL enviroment).

Example:
My site url is http://my-domain.com and the SSL url is https://my-domain.sharedssl.com.

Is there a way to tell MVC to redirect to that url when a controller/action requires HTTPS (preferably in the Web.config file)?

Thanks.

Comment: This sort of redirection is often handled at the load balancer level; you sure you need it in your application?

Answer (score 2):

There isn't a way using the built-in `RequireHttpsAttribute` class, but writing your own MVC filter attributes is very easy. Something like this (based on the RequireHttpsAttribute class) ought to work:

```
public class RedirectToHttpsAttribute : FilterAttribute, IAuthorizationFilter 
{
    protected string Host
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    public RedirectToHttpsAttribute ( string host ) 
    {
        this.Host = host;
    }

    public virtual void OnAuthorization(AuthorizationContext filterContext) 
    {
        if (filterContext == null) {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("filterContext");
        }

        if (!filterContext.HttpContext.Request.IsSecureConnection) {
            HandleHttpsRedirect(filterContext);
        }
    }

    protected virtual void HandleHttpsRedirect(AuthorizationContext context) 
    {
        if ( context.HttpContext.Request.HttpMethod != "GET" ) 
        {
            throw new InvalidOperationException("Can only redirect GET");
        }

        string url = "https://" + this.Host + context.HttpContext.Request.RawUrl;
        context.Result = new RedirectResult(url);
    }
}
```

EDIT:

I don't know for sure if you can read from web.config in a FilterAttribute, but I can't think of a reason why not.

Comment: Cool solution, but I don't it's worth in my case, since it's only for the testing server (in production we have https://my-domain.com). But thanks anyway!